# Converting from Math::BigFloat to builtin float

Tags: perl

I'd like to know how to convert `$c` back into a builtin floating point number. I've read the documentation for `Math::BigInt`, `Math::BigRat`, and `Math::BigFloat`. There are functions to round a number, but I can't figure out how to coerce it to a floating point while preserving as much accuracy as possible.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Math::BigInt;
use Math::BigRat;

my $a = Math::BigInt::->new(400);
my $b = Math::BigInt::->new(3);

my $c = 2 ** (Math::BigRat::->new($a)/$b);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [`numify()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::BigRat#numify) method:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Math::BigInt;
use Math::BigRat;

my $a = Math::BigInt->new(400);
my $b = Math::BigInt->new(3);

my $c = 2 ** (Math::BigRat->new($a)/$b);

print $c, "\n";
print $c->numify(), "\n";
```

Outputs:

```
13719325343735719921671695695860836966789
1.37193253437357e+40
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted.